# Need to prefix JSON document being generated from NSMutableDictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsmutabledictionary

I am able to successfully generate a JSON document by iterating through a `NSMutableDictionary`. This `NSMutableDictionary` in turn, contains two values that are also `NSMutableDictionary`'s, the keys of which are `reports`, and `results` respectively.

The code that constructs the JSON document is as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDoc = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [jsonDoc setObject:results forKey:@"results"];
    [jsonDoc setObject:reports forKey:@"reports"];

    NSError *ierror = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDoc options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&ierror];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
```

and my JSON output looks like this:

```
JSON Output: {
  "results" : [
    {
      "date" : "2012-12-25T16:58:25",
      "name" : "Test 1",
      "result" : "Fail"
    },
    {
      "date" : "2012-12-25T16:58:33",
      "name" : "Test 2",
      "result" : "Pass"
    },
    {
      "date" : "2012-12-25T16:58:38",
      "name" : "Test 3",
      "result" : "Pass"
    },
    {
      "date" : "2012-12-25T16:58:45",
      "name" : "Test 4",
      "result" : "Fail"
    }
  ],
  "reports" : [

  ]
}
```

I am very happy with the output I am getting. However, what I would like to do now is to prefix the data I am outputting with additional details that would go after the `JSON Output: {` but before `"results"`. The additional details are simply `NSString` values like `"Name:"`, `"Address"`, `"City"`, `"Province"`, `"Postal Code"`, etc.  How would I do this given the code structure that I have presently?  The catch is that I would like these details to be part of the original JSON object when I am initially building the JSON object, and not simply when I am outputting to the console.

Comment: What is mainDoc? You create a dictionary called jsonDoc, but then call setObject:forKey on mainDoc -- is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, mainDoc is a type.  It was supposed to be jsonDoc, which I corrected in the question.  My apologies, and thanks for pointing it out.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call setObject:forKey: for each of the key/value pairs you want to add to the jsonDoc dictionary. It doesn't matter whether you put them above or below the two calls you have in your question since dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar for your answer.  Looking back in hindsight, it looks quite obvious (and I feel very stupid), but I honestly didn't realize I could do that.  I really appreciate your help!